# FTP Upload error in PhpStorm8

Tags: ftp, phpstorm

I have a strange issue with FTP - Upload to one of my servers in PhpStorm. Most of the time it works without a problem, but sometimes I get this error:

```
Failed to transfer file 
'/path/test.php':
 could not create FTP directory "ftp://***/var".
```

When I try to upload a couple of times it works again. I don't get it. Anyone an idea?

Answer (score 0):

Check logs in server. And check your internet connection.